# Grails Mongo GORM Plugin - Mapping of Float and Byte is String instead of number

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

When using Grails MongoDB GORM plugin, I realized that Integers are mapped properly to mongo numbers, Long is mapped to NumberLong, etc.

The only types which aren't map properly are Byte and Float. They are mapped to Strings. I would expect to be mongo numbers. Do I need to write custom marshaller as described here:

http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html#3.6%20Custom%20User%20Types

Or is there any more appropriate way?

Thanks,
Mateo

Comment: did you try specifying whether the number is a floating point or double by adding a 'd' or 'f' at the end of the number eg. 40.739037d. Groovy's default type for decimal numbers is BigDecimal which is not supported by MongoDB. from the page you linked.

Comment: also when you say Byte do you mean a Byte array?  A binary type?

Comment: No I didn't and honestly it would not be so easy. I switched this particular domain from MySQL to mongo and it would be really hard to control this. I know that Double is mapped properly to mongo - the code of the plugin simply doesn't specify these properties like Float, Byte, etc.

And I mean Byte - number in range -128 +127

Comment: there is no type "Byte" in MongoDB - you can see supported types at bsonspec.org

Comment: I know, but there is Byte Java, therefore I would expect that this would be mapped to Mongo as supported number i.e. int32. Like the (Java) Long is implemented - I think it is mapped to int64 in Mongo

Comment: Have a look at [Java Types](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#java-types). It will be fruitful as well if you dig into the [Java Driver for MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) source and look at the implementation of `BasicBSONObject`. The plugin should be using this driver (or GMongo the wrapper over Java driver) underneath to interact with MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing the problem you describe.  If I have a domain object that looks something like:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    byte bytePrimitiveValue = 8;
    float floatPrimitiveVal = 4.38;
    Byte byteValue = 9;
    Float floatVal = 5.06;
}
```

and you insert it into the database with something like:

```
def person = new Person1(firstName: "the name", lastName: "smith")
person.save()
```

I do see the expected types in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(7),
    "bytePrimitiveValue" : 8,
    "byteValue" : 9,
    "firstName" : "the name",
    "floatPrimitiveVal" : 4.380000114440918,
    "floatVal" : 5.059999942779541,
    "lastName" : "smith",
    "version" : 0
}
```

For both the primitives byte and float and the Byte and Float values, they are inserted into the database as the correct number types and not as Strings.  I did notice that if you use `def` to define the fields in your domain object the field doesn't get persisted at all, I figure it uses the field type to work out how to convert it into the BSON representation required by MongoDB.

So in conclusion I don't believe you need to write a custom marshaller, I believe it's something around the way you're defining the domain object.